# How to retrieve all data stored in fs.chunks using PyMongo and display it on webpage

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, bottle, gridfs

I'm storing image files using GridFS. But I don't know how to retrieve those files using PyMongo and display them on web page.

```
@post('/blog')
def blog_post():
    blog_title = request.forms.get('title')
    blog_content = request.forms.get("content")
    file_post = request.files.get('image_file')
if file_post and file_post.file:
    raw = file_post.file.read()
    filename = file_post.filename
    DBNAME = "te3371db"
    db = connection[DBNAME]


    fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
    fs.put(raw,filename=filename)
```